# Does jQuery's .html() retain the elment's data?

Tags: jquery

I have a function that creates `<tr>` elements and inserts them into a table. Here is that function:

jQuery:

```
function insertRow(table, key, sort, cols) {
  var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
  tr.data("key", key); //Used for reference
  tr.data("sort", sort); //Used for sorting within the table
  $.each(cols, function(i, value) {
    $( '<td></td>' ).text(value).appendTo(tr);
  });
  table.append(tr);
}
```

Insertion works fine, but here I am trying to access the table rows in order to move them to a separate table:

Trying to access the data (where #move-rows-button is inside the `<table>`):

```
$( '#move-rows-button' ).on("click", function() {
  var myArray, key,
  rows = $(this).closest( 'table' ).find("tr");
  $.each(rows, function(i, row) {
    key = row.data("key"); //"row.data is not a function"
    //myArray.push(row.data("key")); <- desired action
    console.log(key);
  });
});
```

I'm not able to access the data attribute. Is data retained when I insert the row into the DOM? How can I retain this info? The key in association with the table columns is somewhat private, and though I understand JS is not secure, I'd rather not store the key as an HTML attribute, if possible.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet or fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: FWIW: jQuery's `data` 1) *caches values on read* and 2) does *not* update the DOM data-attributes on write; only data-attributes exist in HTML. Consider using `attr("data-foo")` directly instead, if needing to "preserve" data across DOM manipulation. YMMV.

Comment: However, the *current* problem is the use of `row.data` as indicated by the error: **row.data is not a function**. `row` is an HTMLElement, not a jQuery object. Use `$(row).data..`; that wraps the row in a jQuery object which *does* have the `data` method. Then the original presented problem may not even be relevant.. YMMV, but start at the real source.

Comment: @user2864740 Ah you're definitely right, I forgot to use `$()`. I'll try that. Is there otherwise no alternative to leaving the `key` as a data-attribute?

Comment: @CurtisUpshall It can be done with side-banding the data (ie. tracking the data and any elements as a JS object; "frameworks" often use this style of approach), but it would take changes from the current structure which is very DOM-centric. I would probably just/initially change `tr.data("key", key)..` to `tr.attr("data-key", key)..` just "as if it were HTML". Do note, that this also *limits the values* to things which can be converted to strings.